# Why does the verb "overlook" have such a different meaning from "oversee"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences

*[Oversee:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Oversee)*

> ***-verb (used with object),*** -saw, -seen, -see·ing. 
>   **1.**   to direct (work or workers); supervise; manage: *He was hired to oversee the construction crews.* 
>   **2.**   to see or observe secretly or unintentionally: *We happened to oversee the burglar leaving the premises. He was overseen stealing the letters.* 
>   **3.**   to survey or watch, as from a higher position. 
>   **4.**   to look over; examine; inspect.

*[Overlook:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Overlook)*

> ***–verb (used with object)*** 
>   **1.** to fail to notice, perceive, or consider: *to overlook a misspelled word.* 
>   **2.** to disregard or ignore indulgently, as faults or misconduct: *Only a parent could overlook that kind of behavior.* 
>   **3.** to look  over, as from a higher position: *a balcony that overlooks the ballroom.* 
>   **4.** to afford a view over; look  down or out upon: *a hill overlooking the sea.*

The third definitions of each are similar, but even there, *oversee* is used only with persons, and *overlook* is used only with things like balconies.

Why are they so different?  *Oversee* makes sense to me, but can someone trace down the reason why *overlook* often means *fail to notice*?

Comment: Etymologies are often false friends; knowing what something once meant is often of little or no help in determining why it means what it means today. Take *silly*, for instance: it started out meaning *blessed*. You can trace the drift over the course of seven or eight hundred years, but you'd have to know the entire history of the usage to find a logical path from reverence to ridicule (and it *is* a logical path).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some basis here:

Just because you *look* (in the sense of pointing your eyes in the objects general direction) at something does not mean you *see* (in the sense of "to perceive") it.

When you *look* at a forest, do you *see* each single tree? Probably not.

Also, *see* has the idea built in of looking at a detail, whereas *look* has more of a passive action attached to it.

Back to the question:

In the case of *overlook*, you are looking *above* (ie: *over*) something, so you aren't looking *at* it. Looking *above* (ie: *over*) an object makes you miss seeing it - your eyes are not pointed *at* the object.

In the case of *oversee*, the concept is that you are standing (conceptually if not physically) *over* whatever you are *see*-ing, and making sure the object (usually a person) actually does what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Insightful!  I used up all my votes.  Ouch.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) using *italics* certainly looks better...

Answer (score 4):

In the past they have been used with each other's meanings, but these senses have now fallen out of use. Just part of the way language changes - they used to overlap more, but now they don't, and there may not be any particular reason why.

An example from a [letter of George Washington](http://www.libertyparkusafd.org/lp/Washington/electronic%20books/Volume%2036.htm) to Alexander Spotswood (24 September 1798):

> I shall depend upon your Overseer, Roger Farril, for my Mansion house concern; and Brookes Joiner, to **overlook** my Carpenters.

Scanning through the rest of the letters, he seems to use "overlook" for "oversee" fairly often - even, as here, in the same letter.

And for the reverse, from the play [*The Way of the World*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Way_of_the_World/Act_II) by William Congreve (1700):

> 'Twas for my ease to **oversee** and wilfully neglect the gross advances made him by my wife, that by permitting her to be engaged, I might continue unsuspected in my pleasures, and take you oftener to my arms in full security.

Neither of these senses are current in English any more.

Comment: +1 Interesting, but not unexpected - obviously the more divided meanings congealed later on.

Comment: My great-great-grandfather was an *overlooker* in a cotton mill in the mid 19th century: he watched the machines and fixed any problems, while there would have been an *overseer* or foreman watching him.